# Which options of LibreOffice Impress are unreadable?

Tags: libreoffice

Could anyone tell me what is unreadable in this German version of **LibreOffice Impress (3.5)**? Just go to `File` → `Export to PDF`:

[image: export options]

It is impossible to change the windows size to unveil it ([bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1009541)). At least I can check this option ...

Comment: Does it help changing the theme (-> font size issue)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it's "Standardschriften einbetten" (embed standard fonts).

[image]

The screenshot was taken in LibreOffice Impress 3.5.3.2.

Comment: @Jakob: I updated the answer.

Comment: Changed it to a screenshot from LO Impress.

Comment: So I wonder why I can't see it?!

Comment: Honestly, I have no Idea. Window size can't even be changed thru Compiz shortcut (Alt+F8) - i just checked that.

Answer (score 2):

Now I can read it, too: I had to uncheck "use system fonts" in `Extras` → `Options` of LibreOffice.

[image: settings]

Thanks @tohuwawohu for the hint.